# How to change the color of the Scrollbar widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Here is the `Scrollbar` widget:

```
Scrollbar(
   key: ,
   thickness: ,
   radius: ,
   isAlwaysShown: true,
   controller: _scroll,
)
```

Those are all the attributes, but how to change the style and color of the scrollbar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [ScrollbarPainter](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollbarPainter-class.html), you can specify the color and styling of the `Scrollbar` being drawn:

```
ScrollbarPainter _customScrollBar(Color color, double thickness, double padding) {
 return ScrollbarPainter(
   color: color,
   thickness: thickness,
 );
}
```

And use it along a `CustomPaint` `Widget`:

```
CustomPaint(
   painter: _customScrollBar(Colors.red, 2),
      child: 
         ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController, 
            itemCount: 19,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => ListTile(
               title: Text(index),
         ),
   ),
)
```